# intersection algorithm O(n) better way?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, intersection

Let S1 and S2 be two sets of integers, such that |S1| = |S2| = n.

All the integers are obtained from the domain [1, 20n]. Give an algorithm to report all the integers in S1 ∩ S2 in O(n) worst-case time.

I'm confused, why have they given me the domain? 
i know i could count sort both lists in O(n) + O(n) time, and then use a two pointer method to compare elements also in O(n) time.

i feel as if i'm missing something or there is a better way?

Comment: Sorting a list of arbitrary integers takes O(n log n) time.  They gave you a limited domain, because otherwise there would be no real O(n) solution.  Sort-based solutions for arbitrary integers takes O(n log n) time. Hash-based solutions for arbitrary integers take *expected* O(n) time or *probabilistic* O(n) time, but aren't actually O(n) worst case. a domain of [1, 20n] allows efficient solutions using either an O(n) radix sort, or a bit mask.

Answer (score 1):

Your way works, but here is another way that I feel is a little less complicated than sorting and iterating. It follows your idea of count sorting, or radix sorting, but with a slight twist.

1. Create an array of size 20n.
2. Iterate through your first and second set and increment each index that match the value you are on in the array you just created.
3. Iterate through the array you created and print out all the indices with a value of 2 in them.

This is O(n).

Comment: You don't need to do an extra pass through the array. Simply mark the values in the first set, then iterate over the second set and output all elements where you find a 1 in your array indicating it was present in the first set. There's no advantage big-O-wise of course but it's still faster ;) Plus in a concrete implementation it allows you to use a bitfield, using at most 1/8 the memory, as you only have to count to 1.

Comment: @mbethke, reducing it from O(20n) to O(2n), definitely faster. Great point!